# Installing passenger nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, rack, passenger

I installed the passenger gem, but it didn't work with my old nginx. So I am trying to install nginx from the passenger script.

I do `$ sudo ./bin/passenger-install-nginx-module`, which gives

```
 * rack... not found
 * To install rack:
   Please install RubyGems first, then run /home/dbadmin/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails-3.1.1/gem install rack
```

Although the rack gem is in fact installed. Anyway, I do

```
$ /home/dbadmin/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p286@rails-3.1.1/gem install rack
Successfully installed rack-1.4.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.4.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-1.4.1...
```

After this, `$ sudo ./bin/passenger-install-nginx-module` again says that `* rack... not found`.

What might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use sudo with rvm, you need to use rvmsudo - because sudo doesn't run root's profile (i.e. doesn't load RVM) when it changes to the root user.

```
rvmsudo ./bin/passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Two questions: In order to use rvm gemsets for this install by using rvmsudo, wouldn't you need to run this as the deploying user? Wouldn't that be a user that shouldn't have sudo privileges?

Comment: I would agree that you should almost never use sudo & rvm together.  We use a deployment user that doesn't have sudo access on our webserver.  However as this specific passenger command requires sudo to install, it should be run as root or someone with sudo privileges as a once-off.

Comment: Thanks! This finally worked out. I am still confused as to why logging in with sudo bash and installing rack did not solve it though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and I believe it was confusion related to `rvm` gemsets. To move forward, I needed to install the `rack` gem as root into the system's gemset before passenger's installer could find it and proceed.

Comment: Thanks! I did sudo bash and installed the rack gem. Now whenever I log in, I only see the system/global set even when I am not in sudo mode.

Comment: I did use ruby-1.9.3-p286 to get back to my rvm ruby, but even after installing rack in the system ruby, it still says rack not found. How is it checking the presence of rack?

Comment: OK - I have a chef recipe that should get me exactly where you are. I'll attempt to replicate this later today.